# SQL statement to count occurrences in list

Tags: sql

i would like to run an SQL query to calculate the number of passes and fails in a list. I've created a scenario with students and grades to better explain my problem.

I have 2 tables one being
the **student table**

| studentid | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sponge | Bob |
| 2 | Patrick | Star |

and another table being the **grades**

| studentid | subject | score | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths | 70 | PASS |
| 1 | English | 70 | PASS |
| 1 | Science | 60 | FAIL |
| 2 | Maths | 75 | PASS |
| 2 | English | 80 | PASS |
| 2 | Science | 75 | PASS |
| 3 | Maths | 70 | PASS |
| 3 | English | 80 | PASS |
| 3 | Science | 75 | PASS |

**some rules**
To get a Car license you need to have passed Maths and English.
To have a Boat license you need to have passed Maths English and Science.

How would I go about calculating the total number of students that can get a Car and Boat license?

To get an output like the following

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Number of Car licenses | 3 |
| NBumber of Boat licenses | 2 |

I've added an SQLFiddle for further info.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/900a7

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags. Please only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: What is the ID in the grades table? Is that the userID? If so you have some grades without a user

Comment: yeah it's the student id @SEarle1986, i'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a UNION to merge the count of the two licence types together

```
SELECT  'Car' AS LicenceType,
        COUNT(*) AS NumStudents
FROM    (
         SELECT   StudentId
         FROM     grades
         WHERE    (subject = 'Maths' AND status = 'pass') OR
                  (subject = 'English' AND status = 'pass')
         GROUP BY StudentId
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
       ) Car
  
UNION ALL

SELECT  'Boat' AS LicenceType,
        COUNT(*) AS NumStudents
FROM    (
         SELECT   StudentId
         FROM     grades
         WHERE    (subject = 'Maths' AND status = 'pass') OR
                  (subject = 'English' AND status = 'pass') OR
                  (subject = 'Science' AND status = 'pass')
         GROUP BY StudentId
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
       ) Boat
```

Incidentally, your SQL fiddle does not match the table of data in your question - student 3 has different pass / fail data

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not fully answer my question. How would I modify this to have a total number of students that can get a car and boat license?... I've updated the question to make it clearer. Thanks again for your initial answer.

Comment: @Unprof Updated

Answer (score 0):

Need to use a COUNT to track requirements met, and see if each student met all the requirements. Then aggregate the results into your desired result set (your desired result set values do not seem to match your sample data)

```
SELECT A.StudentID
        ,CarLicenseRequirementsMet  = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN B.[Subject] IN ('MATHS','ENGLISH') THEN 1 END) = 2/*Both requirements met*/ THEN 'Y' END
        ,BoatLicenseRequirementsMet = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN B.[Subject] IN ('MATHS','ENGLISH','SCIENCE') THEN 1 END) = 3 /*All 3 requirements met*/ THEN 'Y' END
INTO #StudentRequirement
FROM student AS A
INNER JOIN grades AS B
    ON A.StudentID = B.StudentID
WHERE B.[Status] = 'Pass'
GROUP BY A.StudentID

/*Returned for reference only*/
SELECT * FROM #StudentRequirement

/*Aggregated results*/
SELECT 'Number of Car Licenses',COUNT(*) FROM #StudentRequirement WHERE CarLicenseRequirementsMet = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Number of Boat Licenses',COUNT(*) FROM #StudentRequirement WHERE BoatLicenseRequirementsMet = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *window functions* to count qualifying students in a CTE and then aggregate the results:

```
with t as (
    select studentId, 
        Sum(case when subject in ('maths','english') then 1 end) over(partition by studentid) Car,
        Sum(case when subject in ('maths','english', 'science') then 1 end) over(partition by studentid) Boat
    from grades
    where status='pass'
)
select distinct 'Number of Car Licenses', Sum(Count(distinct car)) over() 
from t
where car=2
group by studentid
union all
select distinct 'Number of Boat Licenses', Sum(Count(distinct Boat)) over() 
from t
where boat=3
group by studentid
```